Can webpack only compile scss files and then applu postcss plugins?
I'm trying to do a possibly impossible thing: use webpack for only compile scss files, and then process them through postcss plugins.
Well, there's plenty of docs about doing something like this:
// [... input/output]
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.scss$/, // Regola per i file SCSS
      use: [
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        "css-loader",
        {
          loader: "postcss-loader",
          options: {
            postcssOptions: {
              plugins: [
                require("autoprefixer"),
                require("cssnano")({ preset: "default" }),
              ],
            },
          },
        },
        "sass-loader",
      ],
    },
  ],
},

But the thing is: webpack seems to always interpret the files as js files, even if they are (s)css. So, what I'm asking is, is webpack for this kind of things or should I use another tool?
I already use webpack for js files with a complex setup, but I'm using codekit for the css things. Now I would like to use another tool, and I thought I could build another webpack configuration just for that, but it seems not possible. Am I right?
